# Функция с N вложенных циклов

Tags: python, циклы, функции

Необходимо реализовать нечто вроде этого:

```
def func(n):
  for x in range(0, 10):
    for y in range(0, 10):
      # здесь ещё несколько вложенных циклов
      for z in range(0, 10):
        print x, y, ..., z
```

Т.е. в сумме должно быть n переменных (от x до z).

Comment: @Kinky а кто мешает? (нравятся мне вопросы, где условие задачи содержит явные недоговорки)

Comment: Уже не первый вопрос, где пытаются вложить N циклов друг в друга. Предыдущий оратор воообще хотел вложить N бесконечных циклов.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for mas in itertools.product(*[range(0, 10) for i in range(n)]):
    print(mas)
```

Comment: отлично, а для произвольного `n`?

Comment: for mas in itertools.product(*[range(0, 10) for i in range(n)]):
    print(mas)

Comment: классно, ну так внесите в ответ

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю Питона, поэтому псевдокод:

```
vars = array(n)
do
    print vars
    # find the index to increase
    for (index = 0; index < n && ++vars[index] == 10; ++index)
        vars[index] = 0
while (index < n)
```

А вообще, уже было ([раз](/questions/235838/), [два](/questions/107519/)).

Answer (score 0):

```
> print x, y, ..., z
```

Между 'y' и 'z' в алфавите ничего нету :)

А по теме: используйте рекурсию.